# Is it possible to view the alias in the Vercel deployment UI?

Tags: github, github-actions, alias, vercel

I have created alias using `vercel alias` command in Github Actions. Is it possible to locate the alias in Vercel deployment UI.

I have tried finding the solution to the above question in Vercel documentation, Vercel community posts and Github community but I couldn't find any solution to it. Is it possible to locate the alias in the Vercel deployment UI.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of today, Vercel Deployment UI doesn't directly display custom domain aliases. While you can manage aliases through the CLI and API, the UI currently focuses on deployment details and settings.

The [`vercel alias`](https://vercel.com/docs/cli/alias) command allows you to manage custom domains in your project.

Run the following command: `vercel ls`

This will list all deployments and their corresponding deployment URLs, including any custom domain aliases.

Comment: I do not find the alias in the domain section and also I am sure that alias is created as I can see it in Github logs. Is there any alternative way to find the alias in Vercel deployment UI?